# How to use angular 2 in django 1.8?

Tags: django

I am novice to angular 2 . i am trying to use angular 2 framework in django 1.8. Is there any way we can use angular 2 in django ? i am looking for a simple example which will help me to build application. can anyone tell me How to do it?
Little help or any link I will appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't used angular too much (at all basically), BUT afaik, it requires some kind of API endpoints for its models to use.  `django-rest-framework` is a tool which helps a lot to expose your models as JSON objects, for angular to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a framework to create client-side applications, while Django is a framework for server-side applications. I don't really see any use case for using Angular inside Django. Perhaps you're looking for a way to create a bridge between client and backend.

You could create an API with Django and create an client-side interface with Angular 2, if that makes any sense.